# Blinking leds on different arduinos

Tags: c, arduino

i want to attach leds to different arduino boards and create a function to blink them. Let me share my code to be more clear:

```
#define ARDUINO_MEGA
//#define ARDUINO_UNO
//#define ARDUINO_NANO
#ifdef ARDUINO_MEGA
#define R 22 // Red led attached to pin 22
#define G 25 // Green led attached to pin 25
#define B 23 // Blue led attached to pin 23
#endif
#ifdef ARDUINO_UNO
#define R 2 // Red led attached to pin 2
#define G 3 // Green led attached to pin 3
#define B 5 // Blue led attached to pin 5
#endif
#ifdef ARDUINO_NANO
#define R 7 // Red led attached to pin 7
#define G 8 // Green led attached to pin 8
#define B 9 // Blue led attached to pin 9
#endif
void setup(){
    pinMode(R, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(G, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(B, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
    blink('R', 5, 100);
    blink('G', 3, 300);
    blink('B', 10, 80);
}
void blink(byte ledColor, int howManyTimes, int duration){
    for (int x=0; x<howManyTimes; x++){
        digitalWrite(ledColor, HIGH); //doesn't work
        delay(duration);
        digitalWrite(ledColor, LOW);
        delay(duration);
    }
}
```

What i want the blink function do is:

- if i uncomment the line #define ARDUINO_MEGA and upload the sketch to an Arduino Mega, it should blink the leds attached to pins 22, 25 and 23
- if i uncomment the line #define ARDUINO_NANO and upload the sketch to an Arduino Nano, it should blink the leds attached to pins 7, 8 and 9
- if i uncomment the line #define ARDUINO_UNO and upload the sketch to an Arduino Uno, it should blink the leds attached to pins 2, 3 and 5

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this?

Comment: in blink function i get the ledColor as parameter and process it in digitalWrite(ledColor, HIGH).For example if i uncomment the line #define ARDUINO_MEGA and try to blink red led, i expect this: digitalWrite(22, HIGH). And if i uncomment the line #define ARDUINO_UNO and try to blink red led, i expect this: digitalWrite(2, HIGH) and so on. But it doesnt work

Comment: The process steps i want: blink('R', 2, 100) -> which board is uncommented (for example mega) -> R=22 -> in blink function digitalWrite(22, HIGH)

Comment: or this: blink('R', 2, 100) -> which board is uncommented (for example **UNO**) -> so **R=2** -> in blink function digitalWrite(2, HIGH)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things wrong with your code:

`#` is not a comment in C. It starts a compiler directive, for instance `#define`. If you want to comment one out, add a comment before it like this: `//`:

```
#define ARDUINO_MEGA
// #define ARDUINO_UNO
// #define ARDUINO_NANO
```

Without the comments you define all three values, so the last definition block will override the previous ones. The definition blocks itself should work, but [the documentation recommends](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Define) to use `const` instead of `#define` if it's not directly compiler related.

That means the definition blocks should look like this:

```
#ifdef ARDUINO_NANO
const int R 7 // Red led attached to pin 7
const int G 8 // Green led attached to pin 8
const int B 9 // Blue led attached to pin 9
#endif
```

This is the next error: You are providing a char instead of the expected integer. The compiler translates the char to the expected byte, but uses the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value for this. An `R` becomes `82` instead of the `22` you expect for the Arduino Mega.

```
void loop(){
    // blink('R', 5, 100);
    blink(R, 5, 100);
    blink(G, 3, 300);
    blink(B, 10, 80);
}
```

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer that solves your problem as accepted by clicking on the checkmark left of the answer.